# Why do I get "Unexpected T_AS" in PHP PDO request?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I receive the following error...

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_AS in ....\index.php on line 98

for the following script...

```
 <?php
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'pw');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->beginTransaction();

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename");
        $stmt->execute();

        while($db->fetch(PDO_FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
            $id= $row['id'];
            $name= $row['name'];
        }   

        $db->commit();
    }

    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $db->rollback();
        echo "There was a system error.<br>".$e->getMessage();          
    }
?>
```

Any idea what is throwing the error? I have checked for missing semicolons, commas, and the works but got nothing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_AS in ....\index.php on line 98

`T_AS` is the token for `as` in the PHP interpreter. It was unexpected when trying to parse your code's syntax.

`as` is only valid in a `foreach` loop, and you are using a `while`.

Change your `while` loop to a `foreach` loop.

#### Update

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch() in index.php on line 113

This is a run time error - the PDO object has no method called `fetch()`. Are you calling `fetch()` on the right object?

[Check out the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

As [Wrikken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358679/wrikken) states in the comments, it will be a method of your `$stmt` object.

Comment: switched, now returns: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch() in index.php on line 113

Comment: Because you should use `$stmt->fetch()`, not `$db->fetch()`

Comment: `$stmt->fetch` ... not `$db->fetch`

Comment: thanks all - I was taking a sample directly from a Gilmore Apress book which apparently uses wrong code then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JM4 Read the book's code sample again very carefully. If it *still* matches the code above, please throw it in a fire.

Comment: @alex - the code i had used before matches 'exactly' with that i was trying to use. I have seen a few sections in the book do the same before.

Answer (score 6):

Because you are using the 'as' keyword in a 'while' loop, which is not valid.   Change the 'while' to 'foreach' and you are good to go.

Comment: switched, now returns: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch() in index.php on line 113

Comment: Should be `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`